# How to move groups of files in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, fs

I have a folder with 600 files in it and I want to group them into subgroups of 127 files, each in their own folder. I've managed to work out how to create the folders, but I can't figure out how to move each subgroup of 127 into their corresponding folder. This is the code I have so far:

```
const cut_paste = async () => {
  let f= '600 Files'
  let files = await fs.readdir(f)
  let dirs = Math.floor(files.length / 127)
  files.map((file, index) => {
    if (index < dirs) {
      fs.mkdir(`${f}_${index + 1}`)
    }
  })
//move 127 files into each folder
}
```

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsrenameoldpath-newpath-callback

Answer (score 0):

```
const chunk = (arr, size) => arr.reduce((acc, e, i) => (i % size ? acc[acc.length - 1].push(e) : acc.push([e]), acc), []);

async function main(){
    let f = '600files';
    let files = await fs.readdir(f)
    let files_chunks = chunk(files, 127);
    let files_promises = files_chunks.map(async (files, index) => {
        await fs.mkdir(`${f}_${index + 1}`);
        return files.map(async (file) => {
            return fs.copyFile(`${f}/${file}`, `${f}_${index + 1}/${file}`);
        })
    })
    await Promise.all(files_promises);
}
```

get all files in array, split array in 127 sub array and just map all.

Comment: acc[acc.length - 1] yields undefined